# Leaflet Polyline error -> "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'x')"

Tags: angular, leaflet

I'm trying to draw a simple polyline on leaflet map.
Function that tries to draw polyline is as simple as this:

```js
  private drawPath(positionArr: PositionHistory[]) {
    const path: L.LatLng[] = [];

    positionArr.forEach((el: PositionHistory) => {
      path.push(new L.LatLng(el.Position.X, el.Position.Y));
    });

    const pathLayer = new L.Polyline(path, { color: 'green' });
    pathLayer.addTo(this.mapService.leafletMap);
  }
```

[el.Position.X, el.Position.Y] - are numbers, but even this simple function giving me error:

```js
  private drawPath() {
    const path = new L.Polyline([
      new L.LatLng(0, 0),
      new L.LatLng(5, 5)
    ]);

    path.addTo(this.mapService.leafletMap);
  }
```

Error:

[image: error]

I did try to debug this problem but "map" object seems normal:

[image: map]

**The funny thing is that when I try to draw Rectangle or Marker it works.**
Only Polyline is not working.

I'm using Angular Module Federation. This errors shows when I have two microservices running. When I have only one there is no problem with this drawing.
Weird thing is that only Polyline has some problems and others objects like Rectangle and Marker does not. So I'm not sure if it's related to the microservices architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wat not sharing 'leaflet' in shared secion in webpack files.
So in both my microservices I added:

```
          "@types/leaflet": {singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: '^1.7.4'},
          "leaflet": {singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: '^1.7.1'},
```

in shared section and it helped. Now Leaflet is running without problem when both of my microservices are running.